# How to change compound annual growth rate (CAGR) formula depending on data existing/not existing?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to calculate the compound annual growth rate (CAGR) for 28 countries over four years.
I do not have all the data. If data is missing the calculation won't work and I have to change the formula to fit the number of years for which I have the data.

How can I automatically change the calculation if there is no data in a cell and also if I find missing data.
[image]

Comment: In the snapshot attached data is only for 2 years, what purpose will it serve for CAGR calculation. CAGR is  useful if there are variations in figures for low to high then low or variations are inconsistent. Second point is if the data is for 3 years only the it will be more meaningful, if these are consecutive years. For 2 years it is a simple annual growth.

Comment: Hi skkakkar . I agree an annual growth rate over two years woule make more sense and I should have calrified that there is data for 2012 and 2015 as well,  yet the data is incomplete at the moment and is also likely to vary from high to low.
So once i make progress with my research I dont want to recaltculate the cagr over and over again each time I find new data to put into a cell.
Thats why i was hoping there was a way I could automate this process.

Comment: It would automatically recalculate, if you have a master sheet and helper sheet. You put your date in helper sheet master sheet will automatically update depending upon your Excel settings or by using Refresh all or F9 key combination. If you desire I can demonstrate the process through answer as it won't be covered in comments. No VBA is required.

Answer (score 0):

step to calculate CAGR.. Excel has RRI function as mentioned in this article: https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/cagr.html

So the formula will be:

`=RRI(No. of Years, Starting Amount, Ending Amount)`, This returns CAGR % over the years.
very simple and beautiful. All other formulas are NOT intuitive for normal user.

To ignore blanks, etc. you can use `IF(A1="", Do this, Else do this)`

Note: the RRI function has three arguments (number of years = 5, start = 100, end = 147).